# Progressive Matrix Question - lines in circles

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

[image]

I was solving [this online quiz](http://www.programaths.com/iqchallenge/index.php) when I encountered this question and simply could not solve it. Let's call the four options below the matrix A,B,C and D starting from left.

Answer (score 2):

> There are actually three triplets of a complete pattern it is two 
>  circles and crossed lines and in the whole puzzle there are 9 circles so there are 3 groups of 
>  circles of 3 circles that make up the whole complete circle the only circle that 
> completes the remaining group is the second option.
>  [image]

Comment: Nice solution. Couldn't you just combine circles arbitrarily using the same logic and pick the remaining one that satisfies the one combined pattern in yellow since the lines overlap anyway, hence potentially giving us multiple answers?

Comment: But if you have tried every other feasible combination and you get answers that are not one of the options, then I guess you are right.